# Zend GData exception when upload PDF files to Google Docs

Tags: php, gdata, gdata-api, zend-gdata

When I upload PDF files with Zend GDATA, it return this exception:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 415 Content-Type application/pdf is not a valid input type.' i

If try to upload other documet types .txt or .doc and  it works fine. 
I use last 1.11.11 verion. 
I add PDF mime in $SUPPORTED_FILETYPES of Docs.php but doesn't work.

I need any solution? I don't have more ideas, help-me please.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken PDF files need Resumable Upload support for the V3 of Google API.  The GDATA library of the Zend Framework is outdated and needs to be updated before it will fully work with V3.

If you absolutely need PDF support at this exact time, you can use this workaround:

http://lamp-dev.com/using-zf-for-uploading-pdf-to-google-docs-api-3-0/289